# Set an hiddenfield as "unchanged" after OnValueChanged

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback, hidden-field

At server side I have this code:

```
    protected void DownloadExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] arrayExcel = Convert.FromBase64String(reportBase64.Value);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-length", arrayExcel.Length.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=excelName.xls");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/Excel";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(arrayExcel);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    }
```

This method is binded to an "OnValueChanged" event which is fired by this little js:

```
    self.getExcel = function (stringBase64) {
    $("#hiddenFiedlName").val(stringBase64).change();
    __doPostBack();
}
```

After the first time the event is triggered, it is fired on every postback. I thought that this odd behaviour happens because the "change trigger" modified by the js code isn't cleared by a real postback.

Now, are my assumptions right? If so, is there a way to programmatically clear this "change" trigger?

Thank you

EDIT1: The "every postback" I was writing about are other file downloads triggered by other buttons in the same page.

Comment: I guess the problem might be here : http://api.jquery.com/change/ "For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse, but for the other element types the event is deferred until the element loses focus." I don't know how focus is handled for hidden fields

Comment: The event is fired without any problems. The fact is that it's triggered also when no change is made to the hiddenfield.

Comment: I was wondering why you needed the .change() at all. Wouldn't setting the value and calling __doPostBack be enough ? Also, do your HiddenFields have ViewState enabled ? I guess they should.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I find the solution. Please refer to the answer.

Comment: thx for the follow-up of this tricky problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was a bit tricky but I manage to solve it.

The fact is: *if a real postback is not executed* (responding with a file is not considered so) the value *is still considered "changed"*.

The only way to solve this problem seems to be "resetting" manually the value of the hiddenfield.

I came up with this:

```
self.getExcel = function (stringBase64) {
    $("#hiddenFiedlName").val(stringBase64);
    __doPostBack();
    $("#hiddenFieldName").val("");
}
```

After the postback the value is restored to the initial one (which is always the empty string). By doing this the "ValueChanged" event is not triggered.

As stated in the comment of jbl the `change()` was useless (please refer to his comment in the question).